# Android Json consult error

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

I'm having trouble getting an array within a JSON data structure is the key "tags" but Android Studio gives me an error saying that this value does not exist.

The consult is: http://content.guardianapis.com/search?q=smartphone&page-size=1&api-key=test&order-by=newest&show-tags=contributor

---

```
try {
            JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(newsJSON);
            JSONObject response = baseJsonResponse.getJSONObject("response");
            JSONArray results = response.getJSONArray("results");

            for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject result = results.getJSONObject(i);
                String section = result.getString("sectionName");
                String title = result.getString("webTitle");
                String date = result.getString("webPublicationDate");
                String url = result.getString("webUrl");

                JSONArray tags = result.getJSONArray("tags");


                newses.add(new News(section, title, date, url));

            }
```

> ERROR > Problem parsing the news JSON results
>     org.json.JSONException: No value for tags

Following is the logcat log:

```
Problem parsing the news JSON results
org.json.JSONException: No value for tags
  at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
  at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:584)
  at com.luistejada.android.news.utils.Utils.extractFeatureFromJson(Utils.java:159)
  at com.luistejada.android.news.utils.Utils.fetchNewsData(Utils.java:62)
  at com.luistejada.android.news.news.NewsLoader.loadInBackground(NewsLoader.java:42)
  at com.luistejada.android.news.news.NewsLoader.loadInBackground(NewsLoader.java:14)
  at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
  at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
  at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:66)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: your code is working fine with me too

Comment: @indramurari : I approved your edit. If you edit in stuff from an OP's comment or answer, would you please say so in the Edit Summary? Otherwise, reviewers may think you're trying to hijack a question, and reject your edit. We can't see comments or answers from the review page.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Sure. I will keep in mind :-) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

your code working fine for me.....please check screenshot, i am able to get tags values...

[image]

[image: values inside tags]

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the above and got the following

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JsonIOException, ParseException {
    JsonObject json = readJsonFromUrl("http://content.guardianapis.com/search?q=smartphone&page-size=1&api-key=test&order-by=newest&show-tags=contributor");
    //System.out.println(json);


    try {

        JsonArray results = json.get("response").getAsJsonObject().get("results").getAsJsonArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {

            JsonObject result = results.get(i).getAsJsonObject();

            JsonArray tags = result.getAsJsonArray("tags");
            System.out.println(tags);

        }
    }catch(Exception e){}
}
```

> Output

```
[{"id":"profile/editorial","type":"contributor","webTitle":"Editorial","webUrl":"https://www.theguardian.com/profile/editorial","apiUrl":"https://content.guardianapis.com/profile/editorial","bio":"<p>Editorials from the Guardian. All Guardian and Observer editorials can be found <a href=\"http://www.guardian.co.uk/tone/editorials\">here</a></p>","firstName":"","lastName":"editorial"}]
```

Consider using `POJO` class with `Gson` instead to make the work simpler. Here is a website which converts your JSON results to `POJO` class

```
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org
```

Give it a try.

Here is the `Json` response I have received from the api endpoint provided

```
{
  "response": {
"status": "ok",
"userTier": "developer",
"total": 8883,
"startIndex": 1,
"pageSize": 1,
"currentPage": 1,
"pages": 8883,
"orderBy": "newest",
"results": [
  {
    "id": "commentisfree/2016/sep/08/the-guardian-view-on-the-raspberry-pi-small-is-beautiful",
    "type": "article",
    "sectionId": "commentisfree",
    "sectionName": "Opinion",
    "webPublicationDate": "2016-09-08T18:49:40Z",
    "webTitle": "The Guardian view on the Raspberry Pi: small is beautiful | Editorial",
    "webUrl": "https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2016/sep/08/the-guardian-view-on-the-raspberry-pi-small-is-beautiful",
    "apiUrl": "https://content.guardianapis.com/commentisfree/2016/sep/08/the-guardian-view-on-the-raspberry-pi-small-is-beautiful",
    "tags": [
      {
        "id": "profile/editorial",
        "type": "contributor",
        "webTitle": "Editorial",
        "webUrl": "https://www.theguardian.com/profile/editorial",
        "apiUrl": "https://content.guardianapis.com/profile/editorial",
        "bio": "<p>Editorials from the Guardian. All Guardian and Observer editorials can be found <a href=\"http://www.guardian.co.uk/tone/editorials\">here</a></p>",
        "firstName": "",
        "lastName": "editorial"
      }
    ],
    "isHosted": false
  }
]
  }
}
```

Comment: I tested the code on another project and it works well, perhaps they have something that gives me the error, thank you for your support.

Comment: It might be that the `tag` was not been sent with the response when you tried. Because if it says `no tag found` it directly says that the tag is not available. Please accept the answer if it helps

Answer (score 0):

try this one it is perfect work for your api

```
url = new URL("http://content.guardianapis.com/search?q=smartphone&page-size=3&api-key=test&order-by=newest&show-tags=contributor");
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection  =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(isw);
                StringBuilder totalb = new StringBuilder();
                String line="";
                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    totalb.append(line).append('\n');
                }
                try {
                    Log.e("tagobj", "line"+totalb.toString());
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(totalb.toString());
                    JSONObject object = obj.getJSONObject("response");
                    String status = object.getString("status"); 

                    JSONArray resultArrat = object.getJSONArray("results");
                    for(int i = 0; i < resultArrat.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject jo_inside = resultArrat.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.i("tagobj", "jo_inside"+jo_inside.toString());

                        String result_id = jo_inside.getString("id"); 

                        JSONArray tag_array = jo_inside.getJSONArray("tags");
                        for(int j = 0; j < tag_array.length(); j++){
                            JSONObject tagObj = tag_array.getJSONObject(j);
                            String tag_id = tagObj.getString("id"); 

                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Why not use POJO class instead?!

Comment: i don't have idea about POJO class

Comment: Try checking that out. It will reduce the lines to max 2 lines. One need not parse the json manually.